# Azure queue: find whether item is in queue

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Is it possible to query an azure queue to find whether an item is somewhere in a specified queue (based on some key property)?

Comment: The Service Bus Queues have a duplicate detection option, which may solve the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Azure Queues** are meant for async message passing, not searching. You should use an **Azure Table** or **SQL Azure DB** if you want indexing support.

**Azure Queues** will only let you [**peek the next message** without dequeuing](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/queue-service/#peek-message).

Comment: Looking at the REST API, all message operations work off the front of the queue (or require a popreceipt, which means you retrieved a message from the front of the queue): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd135717.aspx.

Comment: From the [MSDN link you shared](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd135717.aspx) - it looks like you can PEEK a **maximum of 32 queue messages** without dequeuing them.

Answer (score 0):

Please check [Microsoft Azure Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/features/storage-explorer/). This is a great tool for managing the contents. Upload, download and manage blobs, files, queues, tables and Cosmos DB entities.

Queue messages can be managed like depicted in pic below:
[image]

Answer (score -2):

Of course it is very bad approach to perform search operations in message queue but you can try something like this:

```
        var qm = queue.GetMessages(20);
        if (!qm.Any(x => x.AsString.Contains(key_property)))
        {
            queue.AddMessage(message);
        }
```

Comment: you can read only 32 messages maximum and this is a search on code level